# Angular Material - mat-optgroup with image

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Trying to figure out if the following is possible:

https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples
(See "Select with option groups")

Using Angular Material groups in a select component, is it possible to add an image before each group label? In this case, I'd want an image before the group names: `Grass`, `Water`, `Fire` and `Psychic`. Doesn't seem like the `mat-optgroup` component has that option.

[image: Image before group name]